# Six or fielder has saved the six

Tags: rules, cricket

If a fielder jumps from outside the boundary rope to save Six, while he was in air.

Would it be six or fielder has save the six?

Answer (score 1):

It would be 6 runs, as to be considered to be inside the field of play the fielders last contact with the ground must have been inside the boundary.

[Law 19.4 and 19.5](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/boundaries) are the relevant sections in law.